# How to convert the content of a html element to pdf in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-hooks, react-pdf

I have been trying to convert a part of my react application page to a pdf, but I am able to do so. All the examples I see online just convert the content to an image and then add it to the output pdf document, using jspdf, html2pdf, html2canvas. Using windows print to convert to pdf, just gives the text content without formatting. Is there any regular way to do this in Client side?

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import './Resume.css';
import Template_1 from "../Templates/Template_1/Template_1";
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import html2pdf from 'html2pdf';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';


const Resume = (props) =>{

let data = props.data;

const contentRef = useRef();
const convertToPDF =()=>{

const input = contentRef.current;
html2canvas(input).then((canvas)=>{
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF('p','mm','a4',true);
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
    const imgWidth  = canvas.width;
    const imgHeight = canvas.height;
    const ratio = Math.min(pdfWidth/imgWidth, pdfHeight/imgHeight);
    const imgX = (pdfWidth - imgWidth * ratio)/2;
    const imgY = 30;
    // pdf.addImage(imgData,'PNG',imgX,imgY,imgWidth*ratio,imgHeight*ratio);
    pdf.addImage(imgData,'PNG',0,0,pdfWidth,pdfHeight);
    pdf.save('sample.pdf')
})
}


return(
<div className="resume-main">
    <div>
        <Button label="Download" onClick= 
            {()=>convertToPDF(document.getElementById("temp_1"))}/>
    </div>
    <div id="temp_1" ref={contentRef}>
        <Template_1 data={data}/>
    </div>

</div>
)
}

export default Resume;
```